# Default MONOSPACE font for openjdk

Tags: ubuntu, java, openbravo

I have a Java application  (Openbravo POS) and it is running on ubuntu 16.04 .

Im using openjdk. The question is:

Is there any way to change the font choosen by this piece of code:

```
private static Font BASEFONT = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 7).deriveFont(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0, 1.40));
```

I've tried changing default monospace font via Unity Tweak Tool, but it does not help.

P.S. I have the full source to recompile app with other font specified, but its kinda funny to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [font configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) for this.